# Discriminator not working as intended when using Exclude and |

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I don't quite know how to word the question, but I have stumbled upon a peculiar problem. I am trying to discriminate between different `Thingy` by using the `foo` property which has a type of `Kind`.

```
interface AKind {
    kind: 'A';
}

interface BKind {
    kind: 'B';
}

interface CKind {
    kind: 'C';
}

type Kind = AKind | BKind | CKind;

type ExCThingy = {
    foo: Exclude<Kind, CKind>,
    something: 'test';
}

type CThingy = {
    foo: CKind,
    somethingelse: 'test2';
}

type Foo = {
    foo: Kind
}

function DoSomething(args: ExCThingy | CThingy) {
    function isCThingy(args: ExCThingy | CThingy): args is CThingy {
        return args.foo.kind === 'C';
    }

    if (isCThingy(args)) {
        //Do C thing
        return;
    }

    //else Do ExC thing
    return;
}

const a: AKind = {
    kind: 'A',
}

const b: BKind = {
    kind: 'B',
}

const c: CKind = {
    kind: 'C',
}


const fooArray: Foo[] = [{
    foo: a,
},
{
    foo: b,
},
{
    foo: c,
    }];

fooArray.map(e => DoSomething({
    foo: e.foo,
    something: 'test',
    somethingelse: 'test2'
}));
```

The ts compiler complain:

```
Argument of type '{ foo: Kind; something: "test"; somethingelse: "test2"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ExCThingy | CThingy'.
  Type '{ foo: Kind; something: "test"; somethingelse: "test2"; }' is not assignable to type 'CThingy'.
    Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
      Type 'Kind' is not assignable to type 'CKind'.
        Type 'AKind' is not assignable to type 'CKind'.
          Types of property 'kind' are incompatible.
            Type '"A"' is not assignable to type '"C"'.(2345)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are causing this to happen.  The main issue here is that TypeScript does not support nested discriminated unions.  There is an fairly old open suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758); if you care a lot about this you might want to go there and give it a  or describe your use case if it's particularly compelling.  For now, though, it's not part of the language.  That means, code like this succeeds:

```
type Discrim = { a: 0, c: string } | { a: 1, c: number };
declare const d: Discrim;
d.a === 0 ? d.c.toUpperCase() : d.c.toFixed(); // okay
```

but code like this fails:

```
type NestedDiscrim = { a: { b: 0 }, c: string } | { a: { b: 1 }, c: number };
declare const n: NestedDiscrim;
n.a.b === 0 ? n.c.toUpperCase() : n.c.toFixed(); // error!
```

because in the former, `Discrim` is seen by the compiler as a discriminated union with the `a` property as a discriminant, but in the latter, `NestedDiscrim` is *not* seen as a discriminated union with the `a` property as a discriminant.

Similarly, in your case, `Kind` is a discriminated union, but `ExCThingy | CThingy` is not.

---

For types that the compiler sees as a discriminated union, starting in TypeScript 3.5, [support was added](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) for assignments like the following:

```
const k: Kind = { kind: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "A" : Math.random() < 0.5 ? "B" : "C" }; // okay
```

The object assigned to `k` has type `{kind: "A" | "B" | "C"}` which is not technically assignable with any *individual* member of the discriminated `Kind` union, which was the error you got in TS3.4 and below:

```
// Type '{ kind: "A" | "B" | "C"; }' is not assignable to type 'Kind'.
```

But in TS3.5 and above the compiler does extra checking to take a single object type with a union-typed discriminant property and propagate the union upward into a union of object types with single-typed discriminant properties.  And so this compiles.

Unfortunately as we mentioned, `ExCThingy | CThingy` is not a discriminated union according to the compiler.  And the above support only applies to discriminated unions.  For non-discriminated unions, you get the same error:

```
type NotDiscrim = { a: string } | { a: number };
const x: NotDiscrim = { a: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "" : 1 }; // error in all versions of TS
// Type '{ a: string | number; }' is not assignable to type 'NotDiscrim'
```

The compiler simply does not perform the union-propagation analysis on non-discriminated unions.  And since `ExCThingy | CThingy` is not considered to be a discriminated union, a value of type `{ foo: Kind, something: 'test', somethingelse: 'test2' }` is not considered to be of type `ExCThingy | CThingy`.

---

So that's what's happening.  To proceed here you might want to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you are sure what you're doing is safe:

```
fooArray.map(e => DoSomething({
    foo: e.foo,
    something: 'test',
    somethingelse: 'test2'
} as ExCThingy | CThingy)); // no error
```

Either that or you split the single object into a union that the compiler can actually check, like this:

```
fooArray.map(e => DoSomething(e.foo.kind === "C" ?
    { foo: e.foo, somethingelse: 'test2' } : { foo: e.foo, something: 'test' }
));
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgZwMYCc4FsoF4oG8oCGAXFAAwA0USJCwaAdgOZQC+UAPnoSQIyXVR6AV3QAjCClYBuAFAATCEgA2BFNCQB7erShyS8ZGnSy5AOgLYsOUlAD8u00lPANAVTCQUAYQIIIACgBKKBIzJxcAMTgADwg5IKkoAHokqA0AawIQGRlQSCgAOQhaOINUDGwuYi5REhsWfho6OCZWDiqSfFqoHlZGwRFxSRYTRRU1Ki0dehIikrkyo1l6c1NRS2s7QUdnNw8JHz8gkO3wjSjY+MDElKgJFA0UAEIc15kW4AkAMwIkaABBADSLTkeBkUAhUHSIJIAHJ-rDZCwch9vr9oAAhYH0UG4cGQ6E4uEYxEyZHveifFA-P5QLzY3H4iGEvRQWFeUnkvLQBmVIEg9pYgWcekg2SabTAKEkXk4fAskgAWQIwAAFqYUAQcRp0McADxkUwAVi2ACJ-qaTsq1RqtXIdfrDSb7KaMZaSKavJaRjJbvdHlAWlAACoAZQAzKYACyEHFQcRKDQAd0oGSygfoIYjxtjoIIog0ADcIL7UkGw5GY3b4xBE0mSMHwNBYfKYVBzZbOK7O+2vYkWLDAwhBBopb4EHBGPR80poC4oNy2QzYaYcouCqPFhU5dwoLQGMw2Jx8NVhGIJNIZBKdNFZpvEOVMDvqtb1ZrtbrggbSDmXe6etIySpP6khBgQShKFAxYoBOUxpF8WaliGTZsieTQHu0Z5DP2g6ICOY4IBOU4znOGgLihsIbsAW7oLCbyLgAotEXjBqqLSMCAlR4pCUBfBoGgkExyhCAoeoMpQoo4gAfOQTJ7jqEBquxcKfLQnJrihLFsUwnFynJfECXS4lyQgClKUwtZ+CpxTAAATOpuQoRE-Fcfp-EyiCZI5F8Qj0EgwBwFosAaKGZnaYw-iqIwCCCcxrHsZxIrxTpwTcZCPl+QFQWIFpCWRSg0WxblOntMVHGBCQUXDnhZWcWlPEQmowBCCgmZVaYBmmCyGxshysg8eSPFwAh-g5clHH5dFgSpXJPEpDAZFeAu4WzZCTUtfQ-WQoNkIpJZ0ALVATFLeZjByetrVIjk15jiQ-JxnpPEKmyCKyeSN3xiQQoPWCT1trCJJvVA11TFKAiSaCj0Ev9HJva8H0Gf8KCaiAJDORoADaAC6lQY-VvHuYQb2yfjBkkKIxMyKThNIG9WOyDIiPI1kpjoAQYD+NAWBScFoXoIp4X+NThkQB1-GyTxpn86d1lqRLkJSwL7H7bLdl0WwvhHXF4WJXS40gNNDNMyjrPs5z2A8wtfNK0wnNixoXUClYOCepathyfgZN3PblCK6dKtsqpattJ0BMiz78nS+FquDsihs5EAA)

Comment: I just want to take a moment to thank you for your help on this and my other questions, your knowledge has been instrumental in my understanding of TS!